# More colors than ls -G in file extensions

Tags: terminal, bash

In the output of `ls -G`, I can see some extensions get colors like symbolic links or .sh files. What if I also want .jpg, .xml, .wav or .log to have different colors too?

Also, is there any way I can set the color extensions list and set separate colors for different extensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The colors used by `ls -G` are based on the file attributes (like directory, symbolic link, executable and so on). See `man ls` and go to the section on the `LSCOLORS` environment variable for the list of color values and the order of file attributes to define the colors for each file attribute.

You cannot change the colors by file extension by default. But one way to achieve this is by installing other software, like `coreutils`, from [brew](http://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).

Also see this detailed answer on superuser - [colouring output of ls according to file extension](https://superuser.com/a/468969).